# How to fix INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED in my android application

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-manifest, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I am trying to experiment with gcm but unable to make it work. Don't know where I am messing with it, below is the error I am getting. I am trying to deploy my application directly on device and debug from there but when ever I try to deploy it gives this error

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: HT24LW108632
Uploading file
    local path: D:\Data\Android\AndroidTest\out\production\AndroidTest\AndroidTest.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/Android.Test
Installing Android.Test
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/Android.Test"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/Android.Test
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="Android.Test"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>

    <permission
            android:name="Android.Test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="Android.Test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />



    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
                android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="Android.Test" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**My Device is HTC OneX**

- Android Version: 4.03
- HTC Sense Version: 4.0
- Software number: 1.29.110.11
- HTC SDK API Level: 4.12
- HTC Extension version: HTCExtension_403_1_GA_7

Please guide as I am new fish in Android Sea.

Edit-1:
I have noticed that if I comment this below line then application does deploy and execute but obviously I cant go forward without below mentioned permission ... please help....

```
<permission android:name="Android.Test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"  android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to check logcat output when you get this error, as it can be caused by different things.  The message (Tag PackageParser) will give you the specific line number and descriptive error.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Change name package with Caps letters to little letters.

Comment: but i am able to successfully deploy the app as soon I start putting gcm related configuration it gives error.

Comment: imperator_sp, you were right and it did worked, create a package with small letters and the project worked successfully. thanks

Answer (score 9):

**Change** your

`android:name="MainActivity"`

**TO**

```
android:name=".MainActivity"
```

**OR** add the fully qualified package name in lowercase before your class name

```
android:name="thepackage.MainActivity"
```

Do change all the attributes named as `android:name` inside the `activity` tags as I suggested.

Comment: getting error because activity name is not start with (.) dot in manifest

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

to:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

Try that.

Answer (score 3):

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity"
```

should be formed like

```
<activity android:name="com.company.appname"
```

to do this without errors go to package (right click) > android tools > rename app package

Answer (score 1):

try to write activity name follow by "."
Instead of

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

use

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Answer (score 1):

I met this same issue in android studio

what solve this is to let company domain to be all small letters,

Answer (score 1):

For Android 12 (Android ", API Level 31) you can find this same error because of behavioural changes.

To get rid of it you must add `android:exported="true"` (or `false`*) to any `<activity>`, `<activity-alias>`,`<service>`, or `<receiver>` components that have `<intent-filter>`s declared in the app’s `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

* More info: [Related official documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported)

Answer (score 0):

There's issue about this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37658
Capital letters can't be used in package names within permissions. You got (same as me) into difficult situation when you have deployed application with package name like this and you need to use GCM.
I tried to use some kind of short form of permission:

```
<permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

I also defined service in the same way. It had to be in application package.
It worked on Android 4.3. Probably on 4.2 also. I know that on 4.0.3 it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your package name is in small letters...
worked for me

Answer (score 0):

write the java package name and all folders name in lowercase, it will work fine...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was mentioned the package name in small letters only. But for few of the activities I named it with partial name i.e `android:name=".ContactUs"` . After I solved it by prefixing full package name before all the activity name, service name and broadcast provider name in Manifest file.

Working code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="vcan.doit.com">

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.DesignDemo">
    <activity
        android:name="vcan.doit.com.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="vcan.doit.com.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DesignDemo" />
    <activity
        android:name="vcan.doit.com.CheeseDetailActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="vcan.doit.com.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="vcan.doit.com.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <service android:name="vcan.doit.com.PushNotification.MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="vcan.doit.com.PushNotification.MyAndroidFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="vcan.doit.com.AboutUs"
        android:label="@string/abt_us"
        android:parentActivityName="vcan.doit.com.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="vcan.doit.com.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="vcan.doit.com.ContactUs"
        android:label="@string/contact_us"
        android:parentActivityName="vcan.doit.com.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="vcan.doit.com.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="vcan.doit.com.WriteToUs"
        android:label="@string/write_us"
        android:parentActivityName="vcan.doit.com.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="vcan.doit.com.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. My device memory was full. I solved my problem with freeing device memory.