# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED Error after adding Admob

Tags: android, admob, manifest

I have got a INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error in my console since i added the Admob lib to my project i looked around for hours in the internet but nobody had the right solution for my problem hopefully you can help i am kind a new to android app dev
Here is my manifest i already tried to clean it from corrupt lines

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.keyprod.agd"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SettingActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: In what console? That Manifest parses just fine in IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: The eclipse Console but even if i delete Admob from my project it is still showing the error

Comment: I think you had better post a snapshot of the error

Answer (score 0):

**According** [How to fix INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED in my android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396351/how-to-fix-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed-in-my-android-application) :

`Change name package with Caps letters to little letters.`

**And** [Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056564/installation-error-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed) :

`Activity name should be prefixed with "." in your manifest file.`