# android studio get Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED] and packageName in lowerCase

Tags: android, android-studio, android-multidex

When I run my application I get this error:

> pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.appgate.playsitas
>   Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

my packageName is in lower case and the minSdkVersion is less than the device's api level. I guess this is related to the multiDex that i add to the app `multiDexEnabled true`
and `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

My manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.playsit" >

  <application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Show us your manifest.

Comment: thank you for your first answer , did you have any idea what can it be?

Comment: @EsterAppGate According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19922965/1233652), capital letters can't be used in package names within permissions. Therefore, change `com.AppGate.PlaySit.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE` to `com.appgate.playsit.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE`, and do the same for your second permission.

Comment: I deleted all the permissions and meta data from my manifest, but it's not related to this, its happen after i add a library that i wrote in eclipse and convert to android studio, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the applicationId in your build.gradle and the package-name in your manifest are different. If so, you should specify complete calssName in your manifest, like "com.example.playsit.App" and "com.example.playsit.SplashActivity". I guess that can help.