# mobile-chrome-apps --link-to "Hello World" default

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome-app

using the switches:

```
cca create YourApp --link-to=path/to/manifest.json
```

The packaged *.apk is built from the default create namespacing of "HelloWorld" and not "YourApp".

A cursory rename gave me **INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED** errors.

It seems a bit brittle. Is there something in the cca toolchain for this?

If not which files need to be changed?

Can someone with a 1500pt reputation add a tag **mobile-chrome-apps** please?

Thanks,
Nic

Answer (score 1):

The argument `YourApp` is not the name of the application, but the folder where it is created.  The name of your application is specified inside `manifest.json` and the Android packageId inside the `manifest.mobile.json`.

After you create your application (whether using `--link-to` or just starting with the default), modify those files and run `cca prepare`.  The name and packageId should be correctly updated.

(Caveat: there are some leftover bits that don't get cleaned up, [we have an open bug](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/124), but it should not impact you)

Comment: Thanks mmocny. This fixes the namespacing of the java folders (but not the java file - HelloWorld.java). All of the outputs in \platforms\android\ant-build still are named HelloWorld - I expect the open bug.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is because you have used capital letter in your project name:

```
Com.Example.PackageName
```

Try again using only low letter:

```
com.example.packagename
```

It [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056564/installation-error-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed)!