# Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: though all packages are in lowercase

Tags: android, parse-error, failed-installation

I know this question has been asked many times. I tried every solution from internet but nothing worked for me.

package name is already in **lowercase**, infact i changed every directory to lowercase and had reconstructed my project from the base but still nothing worked

here is my **AndroidMainfest** file ---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.destination"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"/>

    <!--uses permission-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>


    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name=".MapActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MapSettings">
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    />
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                   android:value="-------------------------------"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `meta-data` element must have a `value` or a `resource`.

Remove the

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    />
```

or add an `android:value` attribute to it.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your first activity ("MapActivity") name is not prefixed with ".". According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6816066/4408021) answer, you should modify your manifest file like this :

```
<activity android:name=".MapActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

> in Manifest you declared package attribute with package, so when you
>   create activity you put "." to be preceded by package name, you can
>   also type the full name of the activity like :
>   "com.example.test.Activity_Name", or ".Activity_Name" –  Amt87