# Installation failed with message INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_BAD_MANIFEST

Tags: android-studio

i use Android Studio to development,when I install apk to my phone(vivo x7 plus Android 6.0) ，it alter that:

> Installation failed with message INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_BAD_MANIFEST. It
>   is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing
>   version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

but when i use another phone Meizu(android 5.1) it is successful to run app.
Can anyone help me to fix it?
please to ignore my poor english

Comment: You can probably find an answer in this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056564/installation-error-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed

Comment: Please refer [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056564/installation-error-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed). Hope it helps.

Comment: @Chandrani Chatterjee i read the web that you provided,it said that there had capital letters or missing a dot,but that don`t appear in my AndroidMainfest.xml

Comment: @Chandrani Chatterjee my phone does not root,is this the reason ?

Comment: Please, make sure you have REMOVED the app not only from the device but from every google account you are signed in on the device.  For this go to the google app store on your device and double check that the app at hand is removed from all associated google accounts in your device.

Comment: @ScottS but i didn`t use google account,and i never install this apk successful

Answer (score 1):

Remove the app from the handset and reinstall.