# tsa and tsacert error while running the xamarin.forms application

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to use google maps in my xamarin.forms application. when I run the application, I get the message saying that there are deployment errors

```
2>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore "C:\Users\e245737\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg md5withRSA -signedjar bin\Debug\\com.test.and-Signed-Unaligned.apk C:\VisualStudioMobileApplication\and\and\and.Android\obj\Debug\android\bin\com.test.and.apk androiddebugkey 

2>No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2048-02-09) or after any future revocation date.

2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\zipalign.exe 4 "C:\VisualStudioMobileApplication\and\and\and.Android\bin\Debug\com.test.and-Signed-Unaligned.apk" "bin\Debug\\com.test.app1-Signed.apk" 
2>Unexpected install output:    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.test.app1-Signed.apk
2>Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]
```

My package name is all lower case. Below is the name.

```
com.test.app1
```

I am not sure about this below error:

No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2048-02-09) or after any future revocation date.

My androidManifest.xml file looks like this:

[image]

my properties file looks like this:
[image]

[image]

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As a starting place, it might be good to double-check the various possible causes of the "[INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]" error from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056564/installation-error-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed. In theory that error should be about the manifest and not the .jar signature, so the warning about the .jar signature is most likely unrelated and ignorable in this case.

Comment: I put my androidManifest,xml file. It seems the error is coming from there, but not sure what am I doing wrong in that file

Comment: In case you haven't already fixed this up, it looks like the issue is the `<application android:label=">` line. At the least, that would need another double-quote: `<application android:label="">`. You would probably also want to include a name in that label, like `<application android:label="My App">`.

Comment: I put the label name as testName. This is just a small test project, but I keep getting this error message: 2>Unexpected install output:  pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.co.App1-Signed.apk
2>Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

Comment: I put the picture of both my androidmanifest.xml and the properties image in my original post

Comment: -tsa or -tsacert error is gone and i replaced by Unexpected install output: pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.co.App1-Signed.apk 2>Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]