# App not getting installed in Andorid 6 even after giving 5 as minimum version

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

My xamarin android native app is not getting installed in lower version which is Android 5. I gave as minimum android version as 5 in properties. But still its giving me some error as.

Build Failed: Xamarin.Android does not support running the previous version. Please ensure your solution builds before running or debugging it.

In the errorList I am getting this error even

Error ADB0010: Unexpected install output: pkg: /data/local/tmp/HEET.Droid.HEET.Droid-Signed.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) in E:\A_work\35\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 345
at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass95_0.b__0(Task1 t) in E:\A_work\35\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 753 at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() 0
Error ADB0000: Deployment failed
Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: pkg: /data/local/tmp/HEET.Droid.HEET.Droid-Signed.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) in E:\A_work\35\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 345
at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass95_0.b__0(Task1 t) in E:\A_work\35\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 753 at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() 0

Comment: Remove bin, obj and clean-build the app, Once you do that you will get an error compile-time to add that.

Comment: Rename package name to not starting with an uppercase letter, best to have all lowercase, ex: heet.droid.heet.droid

Answer (score 0):

The `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED` error code is returned by `PackageParser.java` when it detects any of a large number of errors in the manifest.xml file.

From the 4.1.1 version of frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java, PackageManager.INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED is referenced on these lines in these methods. If the source code line number is followed by a quoted string that is the message printed in logcat. if the line number is followed by a Java expression that is the code that caused that error code to be returned that that function should be investigated to see what caused the error message to be returned.

So, you can try to poke around in logcat and the source to figure out what causes a problem.

For more details:[Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056564/installation-error-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed)

Comment: But its getting installed in higher versions of Android like 7, 8, 9 I have tried in that it's getting installed but its not installing in 6. I am running the code on VS by connecting mobile to system.

Comment: Could you please post the  a basic demo so that we can test with it?