# Why installation is failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
Installation failed due to: 'null'

```
Session 'app': Installation did not succeed.
                The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
                Retry
```

Comment: What application? how did you try to install it?

Comment: post your manifest plz!

Answer (score 1):

Check following things in manifest file.

Check your **Activity** name in manifest file.

or the Package name in main activity/class

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity"></activity>
```

Check permission tags in manifest tag in manifest file or package name should not contain any capital letters.

More information can found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056564/installation-error-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed).

Comment: post your manifest file as well in the question also have you tried the above solutions?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.assignment2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.actions" />

        <activity android:name=".Otp_Activity" />

Comment: <activity android:name=".Signup_Activity" /> <activity android:name=".Login_Activity" /> <activity android:name=".MainActivity"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> </intent-filter> </activity> </application> </manifest>