# Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED Installation failed due to: 'null'

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-manifest

```
package ="com.example.MessageNow">

<uses-permission android:name="Android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.MessageNow.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>

    <activity android:name=".MessageActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".PasswordActivity" />
    <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
        android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />


</application>
```

Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
Installation failed due to: 'null'
i get this whenever i run the app on android studio emulator.

Comment: did you check those answers: [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056564/installation-error-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  To make it more likely to get your question answered, I recommend being more specific for what "the app" is and what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

for every **intent-filter** inside activity, service and receiver use  android:exported="true". It Should work...!