# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error

Tags: android, android-studio, parsing, manifest

Good day,

After installing Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 3 and importing my older project (then updating gradle, sdk, and dependancies), I started struggling with INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error.
I have followed the suggestions in [Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056564/installation-error-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed) without luck.

Things I checked:

1. Package name is lowercase
2. Exported field is explicitly defined

Last item that I believe is responsible for this error is in Logcat: Could not get package user id: run-as: unknown package: com.test.app

How can I resolve this issue?

Manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.test.app">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round_foreground"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round_foreground"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        </application>

    </manifest>

Run Error: 

    Installation failed due to: 'Failed to commit install session 1816080056 with command cmd package install-commit 1816080056. Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1816080056.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #137): leakcanary.internal.activity.LeakLauncherActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present'
```

Logcat:

```
2022-04-09 13:22:23.974 14319-14319/? E/studio.deploy: Could not get package user id: run-as: unknown package: com.test.app
2022-04-09 13:22:23.991 14319-14319/? E/studio.deploy: Could not find apks for this package: com.test.app
2022-04-09 13:22:23.991 14319-14319/? E/studio.deploy: Error: 
2022-04-09 13:22:24.008 14319-14319/? E/studio.deploy: Could not get package user id: run-as: unknown package: com.test.app
2022-04-09 13:22:24.019 14319-14319/? E/studio.deploy: Could not find apks for this package: com.test.app
2022-04-09 13:22:24.019 14319-14319/? E/studio.deploy: Error: 
2022-04-09 13:22:24.551 13743-13743/? E/Finsky: [2] VerifyPerSourceInstallationConsentInstallTask.d(2): Package name null is not an installed package
2022-04-09 13:22:24.591 438-452/? E/installd: Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl1816080056.tmp: No such file or directory
2022-04-09 13:22:24.591 438-452/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl1816080056.tmp: No such file or directory
2022-04-09 13:23:08.160 362-362/? E/android.hardware.power.stats@1.0-service-mock: Failed to getEnergyData
2022-04-09 13:23:33.837 8380-9661/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2022-04-09 13:23:33.843 8380-9661/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2022-04-09 13:25:08.160 362-362/? E/android.hardware.power.stats@1.0-service-mock: Failed to getEnergyData
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with error description in error, it's about LeakLauncherActivity

```
leakcanary.internal.activity.LeakLauncherActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present
```

And it looks like this issue has been fixed in new version of leak canary lib.
https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/2076

Comment: Thank you so much! Changed the leakcanary version from 2.0 to 2.7 in build.gradle and I can successfully launch the app on my device.