# Android manifest malformed

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

I\m a Flutter developer.
I write an app in Flutter.
When I run my app in Android <13 everything works fine.
But when I try to run my app on Android 13 I got this error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED.

**UPD**:

The final Android Manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0"
    android:compileSdkVersion="33"
    android:compileSdkVersionCodename="13"
    package="com.example.yulsun_app"
    platformBuildVersionCode="33"
    platformBuildVersionName="13">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="33" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <queries>

        <intent>

            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="tel" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>

        <intent>

            <action
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.yulsun_app.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION"
        android:protectionLevel="0x2" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.example.yulsun_app.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION" />

    <application
        android:label="yulsun_app"
        android:icon="@ref/0x7f0d0000"
        android:name="android.app.Application"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory">

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f1000a3"
            android:name="com.example.yulsun_app.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="1"
            android:configChanges="0x40003fb4"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x10"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@ref/0x7f1000a4" />

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:directBootAware="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCoreRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        </service>

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f100005"
            android:name="com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_browser.InAppBrowserActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:configChanges="0x400035b4" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f100117"
            android:name="com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.chrome_custom_tabs.ChromeCustomTabsActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f100117"
            android:name="com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.chrome_custom_tabs.TrustedWebActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f100117"
            android:name="com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.chrome_custom_tabs.ChromeCustomTabsActivitySingleInstance"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="3" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f100117"
            android:name="com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.chrome_custom_tabs.TrustedWebActivitySingleInstance"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="3" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.chrome_custom_tabs.ActionBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedded_views_preview"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x01030007"
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.WebViewActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <service
            android:name="com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="0x8" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.extensions"
            android:required="false" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.sidecar"
            android:required="false" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x01030010"
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.GenericIdpActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="2">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="genericidp"
                    android:host="firebase.auth"
                    android:path="/" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x01030010"
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="2">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="recaptcha"
                    android:host="firebase.auth"
                    android:path="/" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x01030010"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="com.example.yulsun_app.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:initOrder="100"
            android:directBootAware="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@ref/0x7f090004" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="com.example.yulsun_app.androidx-startup">

            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompatInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Morever I found this issue:
Failed to commit install session 242963872 with command package install-commit 242963872. Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl242963872.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #18): intent tag may have at most one data scheme.

Comment: If this the AndroidManifest.xml you have created or is it the final one that is embeddded into the APK? The latter can be different as entries from used libraries is included. Therefore you should check the final one.

Comment: @Robert This is the one I've created. How can I get the final one?

Comment: There are multiple possibilities: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4191762/150978

Comment: @Robert thanks to you I got the final manifest.
I also noticed an issue from Android studio. I pinned both to the UPD section

Comment: Also check `adb logcat` while performing `adb install`. Android package manager should output a more detailed error message than `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25646008/150978

Comment: @Robert finally i've solved it. The problem was in incorrect intend tag.
intent tag. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

The correct manifest should look like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <queries>
        <!-- Query for tel scheme -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>

        <!-- Query for http scheme -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
        </intent>

        <!-- Query for https scheme -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
        android:label="yulsun_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: It would better to highlight the modified section, because searching for the differences in a text is a job most humans don't really like.