# 10/05 01:55:54: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3a API 34. The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: java, android

Installation failed due to: 'Failed to commit install session 1173230427 with command package install-commit 1173230427. Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1173230427.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #73):  requires an android:value or android:resource attribute'

I already added android:exported="true" in my manifest file, but I am still getting this error. I'm using Java btw. Please help.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056564/installation-error-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14014855/11762907

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If your package name has a uppercase letter:

1. Change all your package names to lowercase
2. Update the meta-data attribute in manifest to have a valid value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).